# Laravel пагинация в JS

Tags: javascript, laravel, pagination

Необходимо сделать пагинацию при выводе данных из базы. Данные выводятся на страницу с помощью Fetch. А пагинацию делаю через функцию paginate Laravel. Подскажите как можно ее интегрировать в js.

Пример функции для получения данных из базы

```
    public function showmessages($id){
    $messages = DB::table('messages')
                ->select('messages.id','messages.from_user','messages.message','messages.created_at')
                ->where('messages.to_user','=',$id)
                ->orderByDesc('messages.created_at')
                ->paginate(5);

   

    $authUser = Auth::user();

    return response()->json([
        "messages" => $messages,

    ]);
}
```

Пример отображения полученных данных на js

```
            <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="col-md-2" style="padding:0"><div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert" style="margin:0">${data.messages[key].id}</div></th>
                    <td scope="col-md-1" style="padding:0"><div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert" style="margin:0">${data.messages[key].from_user}</div></td>
                    <td scope="col-md-4" style="padding:0"><div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert" style="margin:0">${data.messages[key].message}</div></td>
                    <td scope="col-md-3" style="padding:0"><div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert" style="margin:0">${data.messages[key].created_at}</div></td>
                  </tr>
             </tbody>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]